# I can't render nextjs

Tags: next.js, replit

I'm working on a nextjs project and I am having an issue rending elements through jsx. This is my code:

```js
{
        this.state.projects.forEach((projects)=>{
          <Project name={projects.name} id={projects.id} url={`/projects/${projects.id}`} description={projects.description} ownerUsername={projects.author.username} ownerImage={projects.author.image}/>
        })
}
```

The component doesn't render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return an array for your use case using `Array.prototype.map`

```js
{
   this.state.projects.map((project)=> {
         return (<Project
                   key={project.id} // don't forget the key prop
                   name={project.name} 
                   id={project.id} 
                   url={`/projects/${project.id}`} 
                   description={project.description} 
                   ownerUsername={project.author.username} 
                   ownerImage={project.author.image}
                 />
            )
  }
}
```